# Query returning too many results

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query based on serveral email address fields, but for some reason I am return ALL contact records in the org. I'm using several IN clauses, but I didn't think it would cause any issues. Can anyone point out whats wrong here?

I return the same number of results( all of them!) regardless of if OrderEmailAddresses contains one item, or 200 items.

```
    Set<string> OrderEmailAddresses = GetEmailAddressesFromOrders(Orders);//Collects email addresses from incoming orders
    //Get all contacts that match email addresses on incoming orders
    List<Contact> ExistingContacts = [SELECT Id,
                                      npe01__HomeEmail__c,
                                      npe01__AlternateEmail__c,
                                      email,
                                      npe01__WorkEmail__c,
                                      Alternate_Email_2__c,
                                      Alternate_Email_3__c
                                      FROM Contact WHERE 
                                      npe01__HomeEmail__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      npe01__AlternateEmail__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      email IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      Alternate_Email_2__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      Alternate_Email_3__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses OR
                                      npe01__WorkEmail__c IN :OrderEmailAddresses
                                      ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];
```

Comment: Does the Set contain a blank or null as one of the values? If so, then it would probably give you everything.

Comment: You are correct. I iterated the list right after I posted it and that's what the problem was. Make it an answer and I'll credit you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Set of email addresses contains a blank or null value then it would return most contact records since most of the Contacts probably have at least one of those filtered fields empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue could be a **Null** value in set. In Set that you created which is returned by a method. Please ensure that value is added in this set only if it is **not null.**